# Access model in javascript LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a controller rendering model to the view in LARAVEL. Is there a way to access the view models in javascript?

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
  private arr = ['A','B',C'];
  public function index() {     
       return view('/view_name')->with('data',$this->arr);
  }
 }
```

view_name.blade.php :

```
 <html>
     <body>
          <ul>
          @foreach ($data as $datas)
              <li> {{ $datas }} </li>
          @endforeach
          </ul>
       <script src="...."></script> // External script link
      </body>
  </html>
```

External.js :

```
 $(function() {
    // trying to access the model $data from the view.
    var values = $datas; 
    alert(values); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your data into the `window` global object which will make it available everywhere and you can access it from your JS file:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($data as $datas)
        <li> {{ $datas }} </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.data = {!! json_encode($data) !!};
</script>
<script src="...."></script> // External script link


$(function() {
    // trying to access the model $data from the view.
    var values = window.data;
    alert(values);
}
```